# strtok() giving unexpected results

Tags: c, strtok

this is a question that has puzzled me for a little bit would love to get some input. I am inputing an ascii file with many complex numbers which I am tokenizing using strtok with the delimiters `"+"` and `" "`. the file is the following format: `[[[0+0i 0+0i 0+0i 0+0i.......]]]`. I expect the first token to be `0` and the second to be `0i`. I am actually getting `"0,0i"` as my first token. the following the code being used:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char data[]={0};
int line = 0;
char *datap[231000];
int i,n;

void main()
{
    FILE * filei = fopen("signal_subband_16.ascii","r");
    FILE * fileo = fopen("Output_file_simple.txt","a");
    if(filei==NULL){
        printf("There was an error opening the input file");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(fileo==NULL){
        printf("There was an error opening the output file");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        while(fgets(data,999999,filei)){
            line ++;
            //      printf("Line: %d -> %s", line, data);
        }
    }

    datap[0]=strtok(data,"[+");
    n = 1;
    while(datap[n-1]!=NULL){
        datap[n] = strtok(NULL,"i+");
        n++;
    }

    //for(i=0;i<n;i+2){
    //  printf("%s %s\n", datap[i], datap[i+1]);
    //}

    printf("%s\n, %s\n",datap[0], datap[1]);

    fclose(filei);
    fclose(fileo);
}
```

Any help or push to the right answer would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

NEW CODE FUNCTIONAL

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




char data[999999];
int line = 0;
char *datap[231000];
int i,n;


void main()
{
FILE * filei = fopen("signal_subband_16.ascii","r");
FILE * fileo = fopen("Output_file_simple.txt","a");
if(filei==NULL){
    printf("There was an error opening the input file");
    exit(1);
}
else if(fileo==NULL){
    printf("There was an error opening the output file");
    exit(1);
}
else{
    while(fgets(data,999999,filei)){
        datap[0]=strtok(data,"[ +");
        n = 1;
        while(datap[n-1]!=NULL){
            datap[n] = strtok(NULL,"i +]");
            n++;
            }

    for(i=0;i<n;i+2){
    printf("%s %s\n", datap[i], datap[i+1]);
}
    memset(data,0,999999);
    line ++;

    }

}






fclose(filei);
fclose(fileo);

}
```

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hey Oliver I have but unfortunately it runs fine. This is the minimal test case


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char array[25]= "[[[0+0i 0+100i 45+234i]]]";
char *arrayp[25];
int n,i;



void main()
{
  arrayp[0] = strtok(array,"+");
  n=1;
  while (arrayp[n-1]!=NULL){
    arrayp[n] = strtok(NULL, "+i");
    n++;
  }
  
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("%s\n", arrayp[i] );
}

Comment: If that's the minimal test case, please update your question with that code ;)

Comment: The `data` array only has room for one element, but you're trying to read a whole line into it.

Comment: Do you only want the last line in the file? Are you sure `data` is valid when `fgets` returns null?

Comment: You don't have space in your `strtok()` delimiter list.

Comment: Not only does your `data` array contain only enough space for a single empty string, but even if it were big (you assume at least 999999 bytes), you overwrite it with each `fgets()` call.

Comment: @AmmarAhmad Do you need your Output to look [Like this](https://ideone.com/19KP8N)?

Comment: Sorry I was so vague, I do want all the lines in the file and I updated the code to do that (hopefully) but I ran into a snag trying to use - as delimiter for numbers since it removes the negative. anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that you're writing outside the bounds of the `data` array. When you declare an array with empty size, it makes it just big enough to hold the values in the initializer list. So

```
char data[] = {0};
```

declares an array with just 1 element, equivalent to

```
char data[1] = {0};
```

You need to make this big enough to hold the lines you're reading with `fgets()`, so it should be:

```
char data[999999];
```

There's no need to initialize it, since you don't use it until after you fill it in with `fgets()`.

The problem with your use of `strtok()` is that you didn't include space in the delimiter list. Also, if you want the `i` character to be part of the token, it should *not* be in the delimiter list. And you need to include `]` in the delimiters so you don't include `]]]` in the last token. So the loop should be:

```
datap[0]=strtok(data,"[+");
n = 1;
while(datap[n-1]!=NULL){
    datap[n] = strtok(NULL," +]");
    n++;
}
```

Note also that at the point where this loop appears, `data` contains only the last line of the file. You're not parsing any other lines in the file. It's not clear whether this is intended or not. If you want to parse all lines of the file, this loop should be inside the loop that reads each line. And you'll need to make a copy of `data` for each line, because you're overwriting it each time you read a line, and `strtok()` simply returns pointers into the array.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation Barmar. Everything was applied and it runs perfectly. I did run into another problem, using - as delimitor if the imaginary part of the complex number is a negative, how can i keep the negative inside the number to be parsed? is this even possible? Thank you again for your help in the original question

Comment: @AmmarAhmad `strtok()` isn't the proper tool for parsing complex numbers. You should just use `" []"` as the delimiters, and split up the complex number into real and imaginary parts separately, so you can detect the signs.